# ASP.net ポストバック時にテーブルを作り直さないですむようにするには

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.net C#でテーブルを使うページを作っています。
このテーブルはSQLを大量に使い、生成するのに時間がかかります。
ただしテーブルの行数列数そのものはそれほど大きくありません。

テーブルのセルの中に各行のデータの詳細ページへのリダイレクト機能をもったボタンを配置しています。
ボタンが押されたときにその行の詳細ページにリダイレクトするのですが、
そのときの処理の順番として

１．ボタンが押される
２．Page_Loadが走る
３．テーブルが作り直される
４．ボタンクリック処理メソッドが走る
５．リダイレクトされる

となっているようです。
問題はテーブルが作り直されるのところで、ここでまた時間がかかってしまいます。
そこで、IsPostBackフラグなどを見てボタンクリック時にテーブルを作る処理を飛ばしてみたのですが、
そうするとボタンクリック処理が呼ばれなくなってしまうようです。
テーブルを作り直す処理は必要なようです。

そこで思いついたのは初回に作ったテーブルオブジェクトのコピーをstatic変数にとっておき、
ボタンクリック時にそのstatic変数をもとにテーブルを作り直すというものです。
そうすればボタンクリック時のSQLの処理は要らなくなると思いました。
しかし、Controlsクラスにはクローンメソッドがなく、
推奨されない方法なのかなと思い躊躇しています。

一般的に言って一度作ったテーブルを次回のポストバック時に使いまわすというのは
どのような方法があるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

すいません、コメントで追記しようとしたのですが文字数超過とでたので本文に書きます。
すいません。まだ躓いてます。
ためしに以下のようなコードを組んでみたのですがボタンが上手く表示されません。
DataSetを使ってるのが悪いのでしょうか？

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("A");
  dt.Columns.Add("B");
  dt.Columns.Add("C");

  DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
  ButtonField b = new ButtonField();
  b.Text = "1";
  b.CommandName = "A1";
  row["A"]=b;
  row["B"] = 2;
  row["C"] = 3;
  dt.Rows.Add(row);
  ds.Tables.Add(dt);
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: `ButtonField b`は`GridView1.Columns`に追加する必要があります。これは通常.aspxファイル側で記述します。

Comment: すいません、まだよくわかってないのですが、ボタンは1行につき1個、リダイレクト先情報を動的に作るようなものを想定しているのですが、
aspxファイルでColumnsに追加というと動的というよりは静的のようなイメージなのですが？それとも列の型を指定する行為という感じなのでしょうか

Comment: すいません、DataSetではなくGridViewにということですね。完全に勘違いしてました。

Comment: すいません、いろいろ調べているうちに、LinkButtonというのが見つかり、
これを使えば元のページにPostBackすることなくリンク先へジャンプできるようです。
とりあえずはButtonをLinkButtonに置き換えることでページ遷移時の待ち時間を短縮でき、急場をしのげそうです。

でもデータバインドの手法もあとあと役に立ちそうなので
時間のあるときに改めて勉強させていただきます。
すいません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Controlsクラスにはクローンメソッドがなく、推奨されない方法なのか

ASP.NET Web Formsでテーブルを表示する場合、通常は[データバインド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/gg695802(v=crm.7).aspx)という手法を使用して表を構築します。ですのでコントロール自体ではなく、コントロールのデータソースを複製すれば事足ります。

データバインドをする実装に変更したうえでポストバック時のためにデータソースを保持し続ける方法ですが、`Session`または`ViewState`に保存するのが適当です。`static`変数はユーザー別に分割されていないためサーバー全体で共通の値となりますし、ワーカープロセスが複数存在する場合やリサイクルされた場合に値が共有されないため確実性に劣ります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
すいませんが、もう少し教えてください。
現状、テーブルの中にボタンを配置する必要があるのですが、
データソース、データバインドといった手法でテーブルの中にボタンを配置することは可能なのでしょうか。
データバインドを使う場合、テーブルではなくグリッドビューを使うというような情報もあるのですが、
ググってもグリッドビューの中にコントロールを配置するという例がなかなか見つかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @Jogenara `GridView`でボタンを表示したいのであれば`<asp:ButtonField>`や`<asp:TemplateField>`を使用します。また生成されたコントロールを`RowDataBound`イベントなどで強制的に修正することも可能です。

Comment: すいません、まだ躓いてます。本文を書き足したのでよろしければまた教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。